# Discord.js: TypeError: Cannot read property 'connection' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord

So I've been wondering how this problem might be fixed because I can't find an exact solution, nor an exact explination on what and why is it not wokring here.

```
if(!message.guild.voice.connection) message.member.voice.channel.join().then(function(connection){
                play(connection, message);
            })
```

I get the following error message:

```
            if(!message.guild.voice.connection) message.member.voice.channel.join().then(function(connection){
                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'connection' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (D:\FIDESZ BOT\index.js:73:37)
    at Client.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (D:\FIDESZ BOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (D:\FIDESZ BOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (D:\FIDESZ BOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (D:\FIDESZ BOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (D:\FIDESZ BOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (D:\FIDESZ BOT\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (D:\FIDESZ BOT\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:801:20)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check whether or not your bot is connected to a voice channel first. If the bot is not connected to a voice channel then you will never be able to get a `connection` from the voice channel (which was never found)

Answer (score 0):

`message.guild.voice` is `undefined` and you are trying to access `connection` on that `undefined`.

In these kind of problems it is always helpful to set a breakpoint, and then look at the actual structure of the object you are trying to access.

If you then didn't misspell anything / tried to access a wrong property you can either look through the entire object to find what you need or you can go to the [Documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) page to find what you are missing.

DiscordJs newest update changed a lot of things, I would suggest you look at their migration guide for reference on how to fix this.